How to differentiate a differential and why use product rule?
Let's say I have a function $$y=e^{2x}$$
If I understand correctly, we can apply differential operator (d(?)) to both sides of the equation, because applying a deterministic operator to equals relation (=) must retain that equality. So the result is:
$$d(y)=d(e^{2x})$$
$$dy=(e^{2x})' dx=2e^{2x} dx$$
Meaning that for some small change x, change in y will be $2e^{2x}$ times the change in x.
We can go further and take the differential of the last equation:
$$d(dy)=d(2e^{2x} dx)$$
But how to "unwrap" the differentials now?
Some sources suggest using the product rule (on the RHS in this case):
$$d^2y=d(2e^{2x} dx)=d(2e^{2x})dx+2e^{2x} d(dx)=4e^{2x} dx dx + 2e^{2x} d^2x$$
However, from all my knowledge of taking second derivatives, I can say that the result is wrong, because:
$$\frac{d^2y}{d^2x}=(e^{2x})''=4e^{2x}$$
I'm not sure whether algebraic operations are possible with differentials, but "multiplying" both sides by $d^2x$:
$$d^2y=4e^{2x} d^2x$$
Which is similar to the result I get by using the "product rule" directly on differentials, except that $d^2x$ and $dx$ are swapped and there is a term left.
Clearly, I misunderstand something important, but I'm not sure what exactly.
Could you help me understand where I went wrong?

Just a note about notation. A derivative of $y$ in respect to $x$ is often written as $dy \over dx$, but this is actually a simplified form of ${d\over dx}y$. A second derivative is a derivative of the first derivative, hence ${d\over dx}\left({d\over dx}y\right)$, whose shortened form is ${d\over dx}{d\over dx}y = {d^2 \over dx^2} y = {d^2y \over dx^2}$, and not $d^2y \over d^2x$.

Is there a mistake in the equality of $d^2 y$, because we have $d(2e^{2x})dx=4e^{2x} dx dx$ ? Or we omit the second $dx$ thanks to the first $dx$ ?

@Kermatoni, indeed, that was a mistake, thanks for noting that

Since the first-order differential is given by $\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}(f(x)) = f'(x)\mathrm{d}x$, with $y = f(x) = e^{2x}$, the second-order differential can be deduced formally from the latter with the help of the product rule, as done below :
$$
\mathrm{d}^2y = \mathrm{d}(\mathrm{d}y) = \mathrm{d}(f'(x)\mathrm{d}x) = \mathrm{d}(f'(x))\mathrm{d}x + f'(x)\mathrm{d}(\mathrm{d}x) = f''(x)\mathrm{d}x^2 + f'(x)\mathrm{d}^2x
$$
Note that $\mathrm{d}x^2 \neq \mathrm{d}^2x$, the latter being also a second-order differential, when the quantity $\mathrm{d}x^2 = \mathrm{d}x \cdot \mathrm{d}x$ corresponds to the square of a first-order differential. Then, the second derivative of $y$ can be recovered by dividing the expression above by $\mathrm{d}x^2$, i.e.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = f''(x) + f'(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = f''(x),
$$
where $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = 0$. Nevertheless, this result brings the following question : what does the term $f'(x)\mathrm{d}^2x$ in $\mathrm{d}^2y$ represent ? Actually, it steps in when $x$ is itself a function of another variable, i.e. $x = x(t)$, hence the following second-order chain rule :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = f''(x)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 + f'(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}
$$

The problem is in the typical notation for higher-order derivatives.  Your product rule is correct, but the problem is that the standard notation of higher-order differentials actually changes the definition of a differential.
If you maintain the same definition of a differential from the first order to higher-order differentials, then the actual notation for the second derivative would be:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$$
You can check this yourself by simply taking the derivative of the first derivative - take the differential (using the quotient rule) and then divide by $dx$.  You'll get:
$$\frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dx\,d^2y - dy\,d^2x}{dx^2}}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$$
So, after you differentiated twice, you wound up with this:
$$d^2y=4e^{2x} dx\, dx + 2e^{2x} d^2x$$
That's not wrong, but simply dividing by $dx^2$ won't give you the second derivative, because the second derivative is actually $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  But, let's start by dividing both sides by $dx^2$:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4e^{2x} + 2e^{2x} \frac{d^2x}{dx^2} $$
But, $2e^{2x}$ is the first derivative, $\frac{dy}{dx}$.  So, that makes this become:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4e^{2x} + \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2} $$
Now, if we subtract the right-hand term, you will get the second derivative (in the corrected notation):
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2} = 4e^{2x} $$
For more information on this, see the following two papers:

Bartlett, J and Khurshudyan AZ.  2018.  Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09553v2
Fite, MI and Bartlett, J.  2022.  Total and Partial Differentials as Algebraically Manipulable Entities.  https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958


I was going to write this but less clearly. I forgot you're on Math.SE

${\tt+1}$ And the two referenced papers are quite interesting.

I am making as wild guess here.
It seems that $x$ is the independent variable , where $dx$ is some sort of constant.
[[ Similar to finite differences where we let the independent variable have constant difference ]]
Hence we can have $(dx)^2$ , no issues there.
Constant $dx$ will give $d(dx)) \equiv 0$
Here $y$ is dependent variable , hence there is no restriction on $dy$ , $(dy)^2$ , $d(dy))$
With that heuristic thinking , OP Example will workout :
$d^2y=4e^{2x}dxdx+2e^{2x}d(dx))$
The Extra term $d(dx)) \equiv d^2x \equiv 0$
$d^2y=4e^{2x}dxdx=4e^{2x}(dx)^2$
$d^2y/(dx)^2=4e^{2x}$
This is "Speculation" to resolve the Paradox.

Recall the definition of differential. If you have a function $y(x)=e^{2x}$, then its derivative at $a$ is the linear map \begin{align*}dy_a :& \, \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ &x \mapsto 2 e^{2a} x\end{align*}
Then the differential of $y$ is the function that to every $a$ assigns $dy_a$. We write it as $$dy=2e^{2x}dx$$
These do not stand for "small differences", altough that is a good heuristics to keep in mind. They are merely notation to denote (linear-map-valued) functions. In particular, $dx$ stands for the function that, at every $a$, just gives multiplicatoin by $1$. Notice that this makes sense in light of the definition of derivative. If, by abuse of notation, we call $x$ the function \begin{align*} x: \,&\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ &a \mapsto a\end{align*} then its derivative at $a$ is itself(since it is already a linear function, $x(a+h)-x(a)=x(h)+o(h)$) and we would write $dx_a (b)=b$ and likewise $dx$ is the function which assigns to every $a$ the derivative of $x$ at $a$. Notice that in this case $dx$ is a constant function (i.e, for every $a$, it outputs the same linear map)
Now, for the second derivative. The second derivative is not a derivative of the derivative, in the sense I've discussed above, for if the derivative is already a linear map, then its best linear approximation is itself. Instead, the second derivative is the derivative of the function $y'(x)=2e^{2x}$, of which differential is $$dy'(x)=4e^{2x}dx$$ in analogous fashion to the above. You may, if you want, write it like $d^2 y=4e^{2x}dx$.
Now; you may attempt to justify your heuristics in Prem's style. Because $dx$ is a constant (although linear-map-valued, and therein lies the problem) function, then product rule yields $$d^2 y=4e^{2x} (dx)^2$$ But what do we make of an expression such as $(dx)^2$? We might proceed point-wise and say that $dx_a dx_a (h)=dx_a(h) dx_a(h)= h^2$ This is suggestive of the second derivative as a quadractic form, which you may have seen, in expressions like the Taylor expansion of a function, $$y(x+h)-y(x)=y'(x)h+y''(x)h^2+O(h^2)$$ This is fine, but in both instances (this one and the previous paragraph) we are denoting by $d^2 y$ different things. In the first one, we're using it to denote the linear map $h \mapsto 2e^{2x}h$; in the second, the quadractic form $h \mapsto 2e^{2x}h^2$, and both are legitimate.
The short answer is then: be wary of unprecise definitions. You got a confusing expression because you started off from unclear definitions of symbols like $dx$ and differentiating differentials (we don't; we only differentiate functions), and depending on how you interpret the ill-defined expressions you arrive at different expressions as well.
